# React hooks using style in <span> tag, but didn't drawing the style

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am a beginner for using React hooks, so this time I tried to create a simple example but got the result without rendering something. If I modified the value of width, height in 'const style', it draws properly. Could you give me an advice about this?

```
import Link from 'next/link';
import React from 'react';
import ProfileImage from '../components/ProfileImage';
export default function index() {
    return (
        <>
            <h1>Index</h1>
            <button className="btn btn-primary">Button</button>
            <div>
                <ProfileImage />
                <ProfileImage size={100} />
                <ProfileImage url={'https://placeimg.com/400/400/animals'} />
                <ProfileImage size={500} />
                <ProfileImage url={'https://placeimg.com/400/400/woman'} />
            </div>
        </>);
};
```

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export default function ProfileImage(props) {
    console.log(props);

    const [width, setWidth] = useState(props.size || 300);
    const [height, setHeight] = useState(props.size || 300);
    const [url, setUrl] = useState(props.url || 'https://placeimg.com/300/300/man');

    const style = {
        display: 'inline-block',
        width: { width },
        height: { height },
        backgroundImage: `url(${url})`,
        backgroundSize: 'cover',
        borderRadius: '50%',
    };

    return (
        <>
            <span style={style} >
                {width}-{height}

            </span>
        </>
    );
}
```

Comment: what are you trying to do exactly with hooks? you're never calling `setWidth` or `setHeight`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try initialising your `style` object like this inside the `ProfileImage` function.

```
const style = {
        display: 'inline-block',
        width: width,
        height: height,
        backgroundImage: `url(${url})`,
        backgroundSize: 'cover',
        borderRadius: '50%',
    };
```